# how to find tuple with repeated elements in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list in the format

`unique_edges=[('SLT2', 'SDP1'),('GCD7', 'ATG34'),('MTH1', 'MTH1'),('ADY2', 'ADY2')]`

and I need to use list comprehension (one line of code) to move the tuples with the same element twice (like ('MTH1', 'MTH1')) to a new list.

I'm thinking I will need to use something like

`homo_dimers = list(map(tuple,unique_edges))`

but I don't know how to use these functions to search for repeated elements within one tuple.

Comment: Why do you *need* a list comprehension? What happens if you use a normal `for` loop?

Comment: You do not need to use `map(tuple, ...)`, it would create new tuples, but you already have the tuples.

Comment: `[t for t in unique_edges if len(set(t))==1]`

Comment: Or `filter(lambda t: len(set(t))==1, unique_edges)`

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension to find tuples with same element:

```
homo_dimers = [(a, b) for a, b in unique_edges if a == b]
print(homo_dimers)
```

Prints:

```
[('MTH1', 'MTH1'), ('ADY2', 'ADY2')]
```

---

Or if your tuples contain more than 2 elements:

```
homo_dimers = [t for t in unique_edges if len(set(t)) == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statements in list comprehensions:

```
unique_edges = [('SLT2', 'SDP1'), ('GCD7', 'ATG34'), ('MTH1', 'MTH1'),
                ('ADY2', 'ADY2')]

print([i for i in unique_edges if i[0] == i[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`homo_dimers = [i for i in unique_edges if i[0]==i[1]]`

### **Output**

[('MTH1', 'MTH1'), ('ADY2', 'ADY2')]

Answer (score 0):

```py
def move_from_list(item, old, new): #becaue we cant call multiple functions in a list comprehension line we create one funtion to move a tupil
    old.remove(item)
    new.append(item)

unique_edges=[('SLT2', 'SDP1'),('GCD7', 'ATG34'),('MTH1', 'MTH1'),('ADY2', 'ADY2')] #input list
homo_dimers=[]#empty list to fill with all the non-unique tupils

[move_from_list((a,b), unique_edges, homo_dimers) for a, b in unique_edges if a == b ] # the list comprehension line

print(homo_dimers) #[('MTH1', 'MTH1'), ('ADY2', 'ADY2')]
print(unique_edges) #[('SLT2', 'SDP1'), ('GCD7', 'ATG34'), ('ADY2', 'ADY2')]
```

I may have misunderstood the question. this code asumes you want to remove the non unique tupils from the list "unique_edges" AND add them to homo_dimers